# Legal to make and sell a game engine made with Unity3D?

Tags: unity, legal, commercial

does anyone know if it's legally sound to create a game engine within unity, build it as a standalone and sell it as a product?  The engine would allow users to compile their own games through it.

It is a product made within Unity after all so I'd assume so.
Tons of businesses also use Unity to create applications that are not games.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Would your final application be a plugin for the Unity Editor, or would it be a standalone application that you build with Unity but end-users don't require Unity to use? It sounds like you mean the latter, it's but always good to double-check.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/183272/39518)?

Comment: We are not lawyers and may not be able to answer your question. That said, please indicate your prior research. Have you read the Unity license agreement? Are there specific points you're confused on?

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses!
Yes I mean a standalone application that was build within Unity that allows users to make games. :)
It's a bit of a grey area and I can't find anything in the license agreement that says otherwise.

Comment: Would you not say that is something that would "indirectly make the functionality of the Unity Software available to multiple users or third parties"? I think approaches like that would be considered "derivative works of the Unity Software" that provide "a competing product or service" as expressly forbidden by the terms of service.

Comment: It's strange, the thing is that the game engine made within unity would in no way require the unity editor.  The standalone itself is technically a game made within Unity.  It just lets users make their own stuff in it, this does not include code however.  More-so importing models.etc through our own custom code and using our custom editor all made within the standalone.  

However, I think you're correct, thank you for the help! :)

Comment: If you'd like to face a court of law and claim that your game engine made with Unity is not a derivative work of the Unity game engine and is not a "competing product" despite both being "game engines," I wish you the best of luck, but I would not advise it. If you want a more definitive answer, you should definitely hire a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think you're correct with this. :)

Answer (score 4):

That would be a violation of the [Unity Terms of Service](https://unity3d.com/legal/terms-of-service/software) section 2.6 (d).

> You may not [...] use the Unity Software for competitive analysis or to develop a competing product or service;

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying! :)